# How can I install JDK on Ubuntu 32 bits?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I read this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-self-extracting-138783.html) from Oracle but it doesn't work anyway. Any of you guys know how to install JDK on Ubuntu 32 bits?

Comment: I would ask at [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/819996/howto-install-latest-oracle-java-jdk-32-bit-to-linux-xubuntu-14-04-64-bit-ea

All command line.

```
"The easiest solution I have found so far is using a great tool called Oraji 
which automatically does the configuration for you. Here is the brief 
excerpt from the install instruction created by the Oraji developer:

Download latest official 32-Bit Oracle JDK. File name should be jdk-... - 
linux-i586.tar.gz from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads- 
2133151.html

Install Oraji on Ubuntu:

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:neurobin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oraji
Java Installation Instruction:

Run in terminal:

sudo oraji '/path/to/the/jdk_or_jre_archive'
or run

sudo /path/to/oraji /path/to/the/jdk_or_jre_archive
after giving the oraji script execution permission if you didn't install the 
script.

That's it. Now if you want to populate JAVA_HOME and other environment 
variables run source /etc/profile or logout and login.

For more info like Uninstall, Changing JDK version, just follow this nice 
tutorial by Oraji developers https://github.com/neurobin/oraji

Have a great day, guys!"--Chiggiddi (Ubuntu Ask)
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked out! Thank you so much!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the Linux x86 file that ends in ".tar.gz"  from [Oracle JDK download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Then, uncompress with:

```
tar -zxvf file.tar.gz
```

and there you have it. In order to use it you will need to include the "bin" subfolder in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you reference link just follow this one it will work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrOhA-I3aFs

**Command to Install Java are :**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

ensure your JAVA_HOME variable has been set to:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```